# How to invoke a Web Service which requires a certificate in C#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, web-services, certificate

I need to communicate with a third party which has a `.asmx` web service. This web service is using https. I have the required certificate (.pfx).

When first trying to add this service using `Add Service Reference` in Visual Studio, I got an error. I got passed this error by importing the certificate into the `Personal` store. After I did that, I tried to add the Service Reference again and it works. So now I can create an instance of the web service. Nice.

But now I want to invoke the service. And when I do that I get this error:

> 302 Notification: Digital Certificate Missing

So how can I tell my service to use the right certificate?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I finally managed to fix my problem as follows:

```
var service = new Service1SoapClient();
service.ClientCredentials.ClientCertificate.SetCertificate(StoreLocation.CurrentUser, StoreName.TrustedPublisher, X509FindType.FindByIssuerName, "name_of_issuer");
((BasicHttpBinding)service.Endpoint.Binding).Security.Mode = BasicHttpSecurityMode.Transport;
((BasicHttpBinding)service.Endpoint.Binding).Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Certificate;
```

Please use Certificate.pfx and install it with password.

Comment: If any have problems with references you need add. using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates

Answer (score 3):

Try adding this before getting the request stream:

```
ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true;
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3;
request.ProtocolVersion = HttpVersion.Version10;
request.ClientCertificates.Add(new X509Certificate2("YourPfxFile(full path).pfx", "password for your pfx file");
```

Depending on your security requirements and environment, you may need to use a different SecurityProrocolType value.

Comment: Thanks for you answer, but I don't have a property `ClientCertificates` on my service: `var service = new Service1.Service1SoapClient();`

Comment: In the case of a SOAP service call, this would need to be added inside the generated proxy class Reference.cs. The only issue with that is that once you modify this class, updating the web reference would re-write the generated proxy and you will need to re-apply the manual modifications.

Comment: This is new for me. I found the `Reference.cs` file, but where in this file do I need to use this code? The file is pretty large (370 lines of code)

Comment: It would need to go in the method you are calling to send a request to the service.

Comment: In that method there is no variable with a property `ClientCertificates` nor 'ProtocolVersion'. `SsoPocV2.RaetService.GetXSSORequest inValue = new SsoPocV2.RaetService.GetXSSORequest();
            inValue.Body = new SsoPocV2.RaetService.GetXSSORequestBody();
            inValue.Body.xmlstr = xmlstr;
            SsoPocV2.RaetService.GetXSSOResponse retVal = ((SsoPocV2.RaetService.Service1Soap)(this)).GetXSSO(inValue);
            
            return retVal.Body.GetXSSOResult;`

Comment: You need to find somewhere that it gives you direct access to the variable holding the HttpWebRequest. If they have abstracted that away, you won't be able to use this technique. I never use web references anymore, I'm generally hitting REST services so I use the HTTP objects/calls directly.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't have a variable of type `HttpWebRequest` anywhere in  the 'Reference.cs' file :(. Unfortunately the third party don't offer a REST service..

Comment: Here is a Microsoft article with examples that may help: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms819938.aspx. Instead of adding a certificate directly to the http call, they are digitally signing the SOAP message.

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing "The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel" while requesting a web service.
Fixed issue with below code, hope this will help someone and save time.

```
 HttpWebRequest web_request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://yourservices/test.asmx");
        web_request.ContentType = "text/xml;charset=\"utf-8\"";

        ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true;
        ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3;
        web_request.ProtocolVersion = HttpVersion.Version10;

        X509Certificate2Collection certificates = new X509Certificate2Collection();
        certificates.Import(certName, password, X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet | X509KeyStorageFlags.PersistKeySet);

        web_request.ClientCertificates = certificates;
        web_request.Accept = "text/xml";
        web_request.Method = "POST";

        using (Stream stm = web_request.GetRequestStream())
        {
            using (StreamWriter stmw = new StreamWriter(stm))
            {
                stmw.Write(soap);
            }
        }

        WebResponse web_response = null;
        StreamReader reader = null;

        try
        {
            web_response = web_request.GetResponse();
            Stream responseStream = web_response.GetResponseStream();
            XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();

            reader = new StreamReader(responseStream);
            xml.LoadXml(reader.ReadToEnd());
        }
        catch (Exception webExp) {
            string exMessage = webExp.Message;
        }
```