# c# service reference with certificate

Tags: c#, web-services, certificate

I'm trying to consume a web service that requires certificate authentication and I am finding very little help. The little I have found has pointed me to this, but it doesn't seem to be actually authenticating with it. Any help is appreciated.

```
var client = new EjbcaWSClient();
var bind = new BasicHttpBinding(BasicHttpSecurityMode.None);
bind.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Certificate;
client.Endpoint.Binding = bind;
client.Endpoint.Behaviors.Find<ClientCredentials>().ClientCertificate.SetCertificate(StoreLocation.CurrentUser, StoreName.My, X509FindType.FindBySerialNumber, "394507EC60A87E6E");
client.getAvailableCAs();
```

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36181256/how-to-invoke-a-web-service-which-requires-a-certificate-in-c?rq=1. I think your security mode should be transport or the auth won't be triggered.

Comment: I hate it when I do stupid things. Thanks a bunch. If you want to put this as an answer, I'll give you the ole +1

Comment: No worries, and no need.  WCF end points are a pain.